# Fitting a linear regression model in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

I have a question regarding linear regression analysis in R:

I have several independent variables (about 20-30) and one dependent variable. To reach the best model, I try "all" relevant combinations of independent variables in order to maximize my adjusted R^2. However, this is a lot of work. So my question is: Is there a way to automatically fit a regression model in R, i.e. an automatic selection of these independent variables stored in a data frame, which yield the best description of the variation in the dependent variable?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You should try stepwise regression, which selects the best combination by different methods - forward selection or backward selection. Moreover, you can try using regularization.

Comment: This question deserves a long, detailed discussion of the merits of doing model selection and the best way to go about it. For a short answer check out the help to `step()`, the package `leaps`, and better still, the method called lasso regression (package `glmnet`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `step` function, however analysis done with this approach may hit some bumps on the road if whoever is checking your work is against data dredging. Here is an example from `step`.

```
> summary(lm1 <- lm(Fertility ~ ., data = swiss))

Call:
lm(formula = Fertility ~ ., data = swiss)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-15.2743  -5.2617   0.5032   4.1198  15.3213 

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      66.91518   10.70604   6.250 1.91e-07 ***
Agriculture      -0.17211    0.07030  -2.448  0.01873 *  
Examination      -0.25801    0.25388  -1.016  0.31546    
Education        -0.87094    0.18303  -4.758 2.43e-05 ***
Catholic          0.10412    0.03526   2.953  0.00519 ** 
Infant.Mortality  1.07705    0.38172   2.822  0.00734 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 7.165 on 41 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7067,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.671 
F-statistic: 19.76 on 5 and 41 DF,  p-value: 5.594e-10

> slm1 <- step(lm1)
Start:  AIC=190.69
Fertility ~ Agriculture + Examination + Education + Catholic + 
    Infant.Mortality

                   Df Sum of Sq    RSS    AIC
- Examination       1     53.03 2158.1 189.86
<none>                          2105.0 190.69
- Agriculture       1    307.72 2412.8 195.10
- Infant.Mortality  1    408.75 2513.8 197.03
- Catholic          1    447.71 2552.8 197.75
- Education         1   1162.56 3267.6 209.36

Step:  AIC=189.86
Fertility ~ Agriculture + Education + Catholic + Infant.Mortality

                   Df Sum of Sq    RSS    AIC
<none>                          2158.1 189.86
- Agriculture       1    264.18 2422.2 193.29
- Infant.Mortality  1    409.81 2567.9 196.03
- Catholic          1    956.57 3114.6 205.10
- Education         1   2249.97 4408.0 221.43
> summary(slm1)

Call:
lm(formula = Fertility ~ Agriculture + Education + Catholic + 
    Infant.Mortality, data = swiss)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-14.6765  -6.0522   0.7514   3.1664  16.1422 

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      62.10131    9.60489   6.466 8.49e-08 ***
Agriculture      -0.15462    0.06819  -2.267  0.02857 *  
Education        -0.98026    0.14814  -6.617 5.14e-08 ***
Catholic          0.12467    0.02889   4.315 9.50e-05 ***
Infant.Mortality  1.07844    0.38187   2.824  0.00722 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 7.168 on 42 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6993,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6707 
F-statistic: 24.42 on 4 and 42 DF,  p-value: 1.717e-10
```